# Statistics for Document / List Item

Tags: list, document-library, statistics

May I know if it is possible to retrieve statistics for documents and/or list items such as which documents and/or list items is heavy-used in terms of: 
[1] how many modification was made 
[2] how many viewing hits 
[3] who are the users who made the most modification 
[4] and who are the users who view the most time

Also, is it possible to customize statistics (such as adding a few more statistics types) for documents and/or list items? (probably either using the 'no-code' method or the 'coding' method.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer provided by Steve and Kit, I can conclude the following:

`There is no way to turn on statistics for individual document libraries or sharepoint list other than the "brute force" way, which is to parse the IIS's logs`

Answer (score 2):

If you turn on auditing at the site collection level, from that data you can get everything you asked for above.  The data you get will be raw but you can do some excel magic to get the statistics you require.

Comment: Can I assume that only Site Administrator (not sub-site) can be able to turn on the auditing at the site collection level? - Also, are there other ways to turn on the auditing without going to Central Administration for SharePoint 2007 and enable the auditing at the Site collection level and apply to those Document Libraries or SharePoint Lists that you want to get statistics from ~or~ is it possible to go to individual document libraries or SharePoint lists and customize statistics from there?

Comment: You don't go to Central Admin to turn on site collection auditing.  You do have to be a site collection admin to turn this on though.  It's done under the site collection settings.  Basically you audit everything but when you run your report of the audit data you can specify a specific site or library/list.

Comment: Got your point. From what I remember, auditing can use up quite a big deal of resource when the site is big - do let me know if I remember wrongly. That is why I was thinking to have auditing turn on inside specific library/list/site - is this possible for SharePoint 2007?

Comment: Yes, it does take up more space.  No, it can only be turned on and off at the site collection level.  I have some large site collections our environment.  On one which has over 5 years of auditing data and was a very active site, the size is 70 GB according to the storage space allocation and the actual AuditData table takes up 7 GB in data space and 1 GB in index space.

Comment: So in this case there seems to be over 10% more space needed to store the auditing data.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to parse IIS's logs. It will give you the detailed log of every URL requested by each user. This is especially helpful when you are trying to track views across the entire farm. You will need to aggregate the logs for each front end server.

Further reading:

- [SharePoint IIS Traffic Analysis](http://blogs.technet.com/b/corybu/archive/2008/02/26/sharepoint-iis-traffic-analysis.aspx) - Describes loading the log data into a SQL server database for reporting.
- [Exporting SharePoint usage log files into a database using LogParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181537/exporting-sharepoint-usage-log-files-into-a-database-using-logparser) - Technical information for using LogParser to upload information.
- [SharePoint statistics: source processing](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2005/05/29/409614.aspx) - Very old post about this but could still be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that could at least help to find the right way?
"SharePoint List Usage and Statistics"
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/sharepoint/892bae83-5b96-4275-95fd-9723a79fdb14/sharepoint-list-usage-and-statistics.aspx