# Can document opening be tracked in only one Library of a large 2010 SharePoint site?

Tags: 2010

We have a large SharePoint site with different business areas holding individually structured libraries, lists, and calendars within.  The site audit seems to be tracking page views but I'd like to set up one of these libraries to track if a document within the library is opened and capture who has opened it.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to turn on statistics for individual document libraries or SharePoint list other than the "brute force" way, which is to parse the IIS's logs.

[Statistics for Document / List Item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19021/statistics-for-document-list-item)